# How to get matched string from Regex? [C#]

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms

I have the following code:

```
private void button_borrow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Regex filter = new Regex(@"[0-9]*");
        String items = "";
        var selectedItems = checkedListBox_bookview.CheckedItems;
        foreach (var item in selectedItems)
        {

        }
        MessageBox.Show(items.ToString() + " Were selected: " + selectedItems.Count);
    }
```

I want to get the matched Strings from `filter`. how do I do so?

Comment: You never actually _use_ filter, so what results?

Comment: I do. I just forgot to copy it. and it doesn't even matter

Comment: How doesn't it matter? There's more than one way of checking results, as the latest answer demonstrates (which I actually suspect is the method you _don't_ want). But other than that, if you don't know what you're doing, by definition, how do you even know it doesn't matter? Nonsense.

Answer (score 8):

Use [Regex.IsMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch.aspx) method to check if regular expression finds a match in the input string. E.g

```
    foreach (var item in selectedItems)
    {
         if (filter.IsMatch(item.ToString())
             // matched
    }
```

BTW Keep in mind that `[0-9]*` will match anything, because you don't require any numbers to be in input string. Possibly you need `^\d+$`

UPDATE: Getting matched number:

```
Regex filter = new Regex(@"(\d+)");

foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    var match = filter.Match(item.ToString());
    if (match.Success)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(match.Value);
    }    
}
```

Comment: How do I get the metched string? I mean I have "xxaajj8589jfa". I want just 8589

Answer (score 6):

To find all matches you need to use .Matches() and iterate the returned collection.

Another good practice is to compile your regular expressions so you will not take a performance hit every time it is executed, to do so assign it to a static field in you class and use "RegexOptions.Compiled".

Here's a small example, which can easily be modified to support your scenario:

```
class Program {
    private static Regex _filterRegex = new Regex(@"[0-9]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    static void Main(string[] args) {
      foreach (Match match in _filterRegex.Matches("1,2,3,4,5,6")) {
        Console.WriteLine("Match: " + match.Value);
      }
    }
  }
```